# Do I have to shut down mail services in OS X server before doing a backup?

Tags: email, backup, mac-osx

I am using superduper to mirror my server  harddrive nightly.   Should I be shutting down the mail services before I do this.

Or any other service?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OS X server uses Postfix for mail. It's reasonably safe to back up a host while Postfix is running.  After restoring the queue may be a little messed up.  These queue problems can be repaired by running `postsuper -s` after restoring.  In fact, `postsuper -s` is required after restoring even if you don't shut down Postfix.  Postfix relies on certain files in its queue having a name that's the same as their inode number.  Obviously, this can no longer be guaranteed after restoring from backup.

Regarding other services:  Hard to say without knowing what other services you're running.  Databases, for example, frequently require special care when backing up.